# match string in columns with other lists, add match results in new column/row

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

i'm new to pandas :D
recently i got a task, which i needed to process and analyze the data in a csv file.
Now in the last step I need to match the data from one of the columns in the csv file with two existing lists, and if the matching is successful, write the corresponding element of the lists to the corresponding column in the csv file.

for example:

[data source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNH2v.png)

list1 = ['I like cats.', 'Jim hates frog.']
list2 = ['Cats are cute.', 'Cats eat fish.', 'Dogs are cute.', 'My cat has nice fur.', 'Sandy sent me a nice cat toy.']

and the ideal output is:
[ideal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyKRC.png)

i've tried "for-loop" in "for-loop", but the real file is very huge, so it works pretty slow...
thank you very much!

Comment: You don't have very much detail here, but what you might want to do is convert list1 and list2 to sets, then use `object in set` to test whether strings are in them. It should be much faster than a for loop, but you might have to do something else if you want to ignore capitalization as it looks like you do.

Comment: ye, i use the "re" to ignore capitalization. I'm trying to use set to see if I can let it run faster.